# Get creation timestamp in row metadata in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a function or command that provides the row creation timestamp thru metadata in ADX?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ingestion_time()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ingestiontimefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

Returns the approximate time at which the current record was ingested.

This function must be used in the context of a table of ingested data for which the [IngestionTime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/ingestiontimepolicy) was enabled when the data was ingested. Otherwise, this function produces null values.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants the commands exactly:

```
.alter table TableName policy ingestiontime true
```

Then to view the times:

```
TableName
| extend ingestion_time()
| sort by ingestion_time()
```

Replace **TableName** with your table name, hope this helped!